# What is the "gauge field" on the base space in a gauge field theory?

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Suppose we have a principal $G$-bundle $P\xrightarrow{\pi} M$,
and we want to consider a classical gauge field theory (with a field Lagrangian) on $M$ for this bundle, in the physics sense.

In the physics literature they seem to use a "gauge field" on $M$,
which seems to me to be $s^*A$ where $s$ is a (global? local?) section of $\pi$ and $A$ is a principal bundle connection (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(principal_bundle)#Formal_definition)).

My question is, do we assume $\pi$ admits a global section $s$ then work with $s^*A$ as the gauge field? In which case the principal bundle would be globally trivial?

Furthermore, in the above case wouldn't the theory depend in some nontrivial way on the choice of section (e.g. its homotopy class)?

Or, do we consider $M$ to be covered by a collection of local sections, and we assume that the Lagrangian/action is invariant under the "transition maps" between $s_i^*A$ and $s_j^*A$?

Comment: Choosing a local section $s$ is called *fixing a gauge*; in general, it can only be done locally. It might be useful to look at a simple case like classical electromagnetism first.

Comment: I see. In this case, what is the "global gauge field" without any choices of local sections? Or, is the gauge field viewed as a choice of connection together with choices of local sections?

Comment: Different authors use the term "gauge field" differerently, but the relevant global field is $A$ itself, viewed as a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-form on $P$. The point is that $A$ uniquely describes the field globally, whereas $s^*A$ only describes it *up to gauge transformations* (i.e. changes of local trivialization).